# Выполнить поиск по тексту ссылки при нажатии на неё

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть большое количество ссылок и форма поиска.
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, текст внутри неё вставлялся в форму поиска и выполнялся поиск?

```html
<form>
   <input type="search" class="searher-inp">
   <input type="submit" class="submiter-btn">
</form>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст для поиска</a>
```

Comment: 1. Повесить listener на клик 2. При щелчке получать текст 3. Вписывать текст в форму и вызывать submit формы. С чем возникла сложность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // При загрузке документа
        let a = document.querySelectorAll('.link-to-search'); // Получаем ссылки по классу
        let search = document.querySelector('.searher-inp'); // Получаем поле ввода
        let send = document.querySelector('.submiter-btn'); // Получаем кнопку
        a.forEach(function (c) { // Для всех ссылок
            c.addEventListener('click', function (e) { // Отслеживаем нажатие
                search.value = c.innerText; // Вводим текст в поле поиска
                send.click(); // Нажимаем кнопку 
            })
        })
    })
```

```css
    .link-to-search{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="search" class="searher-inp">
    <input type="submit" class="submiter-btn">
</form>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст для поиска1</a>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст для поиска2</a>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст для поиска3</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как сделать, чтобы из текста ссылки отсекались кавычки ""

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Имеется ввиду, если в тексте есть ковычки дополнительные, то их удалить? Просто на текущий момент в поле передаётся значение без ковычек.

Comment: Да, верно, сейчас ссылка без кавычек, но у меня имеются с ними. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как их отфильтровать, если имеются

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Для фильтрации поставьте `search.value = c.innerText.replace(/"/g, '');` вместо `search.value = c.innerText;`.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переписать `search.value = c.innerText.replace(/"/g, '');`, чтобы парсился текст ссылки, но вместо поиска выбирался `<option>` с аналогичным текстом в `<select>`

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Добавил дополнительный ответ. Но, постарайтесь, пожалуйста, задавать вопросы отдельно. Чтобы те, кто так же столкнётся с подобной задачей, смог найти нужное решение. Спасибо.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Да тут вроде ничего сложного ))) Сижу тут изучаю Ваши работы.... Не... Не дано мне такие вещи на css делать.  Хотел попробовать анимацию ту stackoverflow, но ничего путного не вышло.

Answer (score 2):

Дополнительный ответ(По просьбе ТС):
Выбирать значения в поле `select`, вместо записи в поле поиска:

**P.S** + убирать кавычки из текста в ссылке.

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // При загрузке документа
        let a = document.querySelectorAll('.link-to-search'); // Получаем ссылки по классу
        let sel = document.querySelector('#sel'); // Получаем поле ввода
        a.forEach(function (c) { // Для всех ссылок
            c.addEventListener('click', function (e) { // Отслеживаем нажатие
                sel.value = c.innerText.replace(/"/g, '');
            })
        })
    })
```

```css
    .link-to-search{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option value="Текст для поиска1">Текст для поиска1</option>
    <option value="Текст для поиска2">Текст для поиска2</option>
    <option value="Текст для поиска3">Текст для поиска3</option>
</select>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст для поиска1</a>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст "для" поиска2</a>
<a class="link-to-search">Текст для поиска3</a>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть с ошибкой general.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: @QuickBrownFox В файле `general.js` У Вас находится зацикленная функция. Больше можно будет сказать только увидев код.

Comment: Матерится вот на этот отрывок: `window.onpopstate = function(e) {
 location.href = document.location
};`

Comment: @QuickBrownFox `location.href` - это попытка отправить Вас на другую страницу. `document.location` - это текущая страница. Соответственно Вы пытаетесь отправить себя на эту же страницу, на которой находитесь. Ввиду этого через несколько попыток и выходит у Вас ошибка.